# Importance sampling for Coulomb potential

Tags: computational-physics, integration, coulombs-law, stochastic-processes

The integral I have to solve is:

$$I=\int\int d \mathbf{r}d \mathbf{r}' \frac{\Phi(\mathbf{r})\Phi(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}$$

It is a six-dimensional integral which I am going to solve using  [the Monte-Carlo integration method with importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration#Importance_sampling_algorithm).
My question is how do people usually do the importance sampling for this kind of integrals to get rid of strong non-uniformity caused by the factor $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}$. The distribution function should be something like $\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}$ in six-dimension space. How do I generate such random vectors that follow mentioned above distribution function?

Comment: Normally one just draws $n$ **uniform random deviates** (in the range $[a,b]$) for Monte Carlo integration. Who told you to use $\chi^2$? What *are* you getting compared to what you *should* get?

Comment: What does n mean? Isn't that the MC with the uniform distribution can be speed up by importance sampling?

Comment: $n$ is the number of random points you're using. I have no idea what your second sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: I have reformulated my question with more details

Comment: Did you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm, which was linked from the Wiki page linked in your question?